# Symfony2: How to get the current route in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm using `Ajax` to change data in a page. So, I want to know that what is the current route in order to call to different functions. I have read many solutions used to retrieve the current url and also to get the current route in `Controller` and `Twig`. However, is there any possible way to achieve this in `javascript` or `jQuery`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_patient').change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        // Get the current route
        var route = ??;  // <----------------Want to get the current route
        if(route === 'route1'){
            functionForRoute2(id,route)
        }
        else{
            functionForRoute2(id,route);
        }
    });
});
```

** Function for the `Route1` **

```
function functionForRoute1(id,route){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Routing.generate(route),
        data: JSON.stringify({id:id}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            // Execute some specific data for route1
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

** Function for the `Route2` **

```
function functionForRoute2(id,route){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Routing.generate(route),
        data: JSON.stringify({id:id}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            // Execute some specific data for route2
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I would do is to output route (any route you want) in a html tag for example (twig version):

```
<div id="my-route" data-route"{{ path("my_route") }}"></div>
```

Then in your code I would retrive that route via jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_patient').change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();

        var route = $('my-route').data('route');       
    });
});
```

You can also change path("my_route") to a string with a name of the route and then you are doing your if/else statement. However I dont think its a good idea as if your route name changes then your code will be affected as well

Answer (score 1):

You will not get current route using just Javascript or JQuery. You can, however, get current URL with Javascript or current route using Twig.

Another possible solution is to issue one more AJAX call to server passing current URL, then match it to the correct route and send it back. However, if I were you, I would just get the current route from Twig.